What is the fastest way to sort a numpy array where each element is a tuple
Suppose I have a numpy array of shape [N, 2]. I want to sort the array by treating each row as a tuple of 2 elements. I only need the sorted index, without the need to return the sorted array.
Since numpy does not support this operation directly, I have tried using structured array in the following way:
a = np.empty(N, dtype=[('f0', int), ('f1', int)])
a['f0'] = x
a['f1'] = y
index = np.argsort(a)

However, I found that the code is extremely slow, at least 100 times slower than sorting a standard numpy array. I am quite confused why the argsort operation is extremely slow for structured array. And I would like to see any faster implementation. Thank you!

Your question is unclear and your example is not reproducible (see. [mre]). Do you want to lexsort?

Technically the rows of your (N,2) array aren't tuples.  Converted to a structured array, they display as tuples, but are actually 'records'.  'tuples' don't have a natural order.  That's why sorting a structured array is more like lexsort.  One field (or column) has prioity etc.
